# Invalidate() causes NULL POINTER exception on programmatically addedd control (c#)

Tags: c#, user-controls, nullpointerexception

When I add a PictureBox to my form like this:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    PictureBox _pb;

    public formMain(){

    _pb = new PictureBox();
    formMain.Controls.Add(_pb);
    }

    //SOME METHOD
    private void SomeMethod(){
        _pb.Invalidate();  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

What's going on here?  Is more needed to add a control to a form?

More info:

If I drag a picturebox to the "form designer"  in visual studio C#,  and name it _pb.
The above works.  Are there additional steps to adding a control programmatically?  More than just calling Form.Controls.Add(/*some control*/)  ???

Answer (score 1):

Really just a hunch, would need to see the full class and not just pieces of it. But one curiosity is that you have:

formMain.Controls.Add

in a constructor for formMain, where is the variable formMain defined (assuming this compiles). Don't you mean:

this.Controls.Add(_pb)

Not sure if this the problem, I suspect that the problem could also be that _pb is not defined by the time that it invalidate is called. Do you have any other constructors that are used that don't initialized _pb?

Comment: I'm new at this, but I just created a new C# window application in Visual Studio C#. And named the form "formMain." I'm not really sure where VS defines the the form.